# javascript Regexp - Match particular number combination

Tags: javascript, regex

I am try to match all number combination using regexp from text string.

Example:

Input : **001**
TextString:**000,001,006,010,007,100,0015,0010**

My Match will be like this
**001,010,100** only.

I tried a lot of things but i can not find exact solution.

Advance thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how regex would help you there. Just produce every combination of your input characters and search them as plain-text in the string.

Comment: You'll have to clarify. Are you trying to match the input against allowed values in the string?

Comment: @Aaron actually, my input was more than 2000 numbers. if I generate the combination for all numbers and match with my string, takes quite a long process. that's why I try to find some other way.

Comment: @ClasG yes. I wanna match my input with my string and find all possible combination. I already to find by using this pattern. /([^0-9]|^)[001]{3}(,[001]{3})*([^0-9])|$)/gm. but no luck. I got the issue with some other scenarios

Answer (score 1):

Use `split`, `join` and finally `filter`

```
var splitNSortNJoin = (s) => s.split("").sort().join("");

var output = input.split(/,/).filter(s => splitNSortNJoin(s) == splitNSortNJoin( matchStr ) );
```

**Demo**

```js
var input = "000,001,006,010,007,100,0015,0010";
var matchStr = "001";


var splitNSortNJoin = (s) => s.split("").sort().join("");

var output = input.split(/,/).filter(s => splitNSortNJoin(s) == splitNSortNJoin( matchStr ) );

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Awesome. thanks for the quick response. really appreciate your help. thanks again.